# Dividing records into equal groups, but with some records in specific groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to divide a set of records up as evenly as possible, but some records are required to be in specific groups.

Say I have 200 records:

- 60 in Set A,
- 20 in Set B,
- 120 in Set C.

I need to divide them into 4 Groups but:

- Set A must always be in Group 1.
- Set B must always be in Group 2.
- Set C can be in any group.

I tried using NTILE (something like `SELECT *, NTILE(4) OVER (ORDER BY Set) FROM Table`) but it doesn't get there with splitting up the records correctly.

Set A is more than 1/4 of all records, so no records from Set C can be in Group 1, I need to divide up Set C so that my groups look like this:

| Group | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 47 |
| 3 | 47 |
| 4 | 46 |

Where any group that is larger than [the total number of records / count of groups] has all its required members, while any group that is smaller than the group size is in its required group and the remaining space filled with unassigned records, and the remaining groups filled with whatever records haven't already been assigned a specific group.